# Specify the column width in a Shiny fluid page

Tags: r, shiny

I have a layout in Shiny like this

```
 shinyUI(fluidPage(
     tags$head(tags$script(src="lib.js"))
    ,tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "thispage.css")
    ,titlePanel("Inbound Level Shift Detector")
     ,mainPanel(
         tabsetPanel(type ...
```

The corresponding HTML source is

```
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="thispage.css"/>
    <h2>Inbound Level Shift Detector</h2>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <div class="tabbable tabs-above">
```

How can i specify in the R code to make the top level be a `col-sm-12` instead of `col-sm-8`?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Use mainPanel(..., width=12). That ought to work.